# getting data from 2 tables not unique to any one table

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have 2 mysql tables

```
table 1
 ----------
 id | Name | Size
 ------------------ 
 1 | Frank | Small
 2 | Steve | Medium
 3 | Joe   | Large
 4 | Tina  | Small
 5 | Bob   | Small


 table 2
 --------
 id | Name | Size
 ------------------ 
 1  | Hank |  Small
 2  | Ed   |  Large
 3  | Bill |  Small
```

What query can i write to get all persons from table1 and table 2 where  size='small' on 1 query?

The result should be "Frank,Tina,Bob,Hank, and Bill"

The only queries i can find tie the tables together and i don't necessarily need to do that.  The real world application has some sensitive data in the tables... Table 1 is standard config settings, and table 2 is custom config settings in real world.

full outer join looks promising, but cant figure out syntax.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is `union`:

```
select name
from table1
where size='small'
UNION
select name
from table2
where size='small';
```

Comment: . . You have a high enough reputation that you should know how to format responses on Stack Overflow.  (Note:  I am not the downvoter, just the editor.)  I left the mistake in the query, but I figure it is easy enough to figure out how to get the name instead of the size.